# Is interprocess communication relevant on the iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is interprocess communication relevant on the iPhone or iPad? Because there's NSPipe available...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stock iOS sandbox does not allow an app to start another process or communicate with any other process on the device directly (except using a public API).

You might be able to use pipes for communication between threads within an apps single process space.

Answer (score 2):

Not for the current iPad (which I'm typing this on), but iOS4 supports multi-tasking so presumably it is more relevant there?